# How to undo background-color on a:focus?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Twitter Bootstrap has `background-color` properties set for navigation items on their `:focus` state, but I want to undo that declaration for a specific navigation element.

For example, in some custom theme, let's say when the navigation item is in its default state, its background color is dark red. And then when you hover over it, it changes to light red.

Then, because of Bootstrap's declaration for the `:focus` state, if you click a navigation item, and move your mouse away from it, it will become light grey (from the default Bootsrap theme). This is what I want to get rid of.

What I want to achieve here is that, when you click an item, it should keep its default behavior, meaning dark red without the mouse over, and light red when the mouse is over it. But this doesn't work, because the `:focus` state seems to override the `:hover` state, so whatever I try to declare for `:focus`, works for both mouse over and mouse away.

I've also tried with `background-color:transparent`, and `background-color:inherit`. But the problem is always the same, which is that, whatever the color renders to, it keep being that regardless of the mouse being over the link or not. I want the background color to keep changing on hover, even when that link gets focus.

Comment: Try !important. `background-color: transparent !important`.

Comment: I don't think you understood what I wanted. If I set the background color as important (or at all really), it will override the `hover` state, so both the hover and non-hover will be the same (in this case transparent).Which is what I don't want.

Comment: Can you provide a codepen for your example?

Comment: @lix http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RorMJq

Answer (score 0):

in your special element put an extra class and set the css.

```
.ExtraClass:focus{
    color: #FFF !important;
}

.ExtraClass:hover{
    color: #000 !important;
}

.ExtraClass{
    color:#555 !important;
}
```